# Background and Text on a Button

Tags: android, android-widget

like said in the title I'd like to change a button's backgroun (using setBackgroundResource() ), but when I do that, I can't see the text I'm puting on it (with setText() ), I found similar subject, but only with xml anwser. I need to do this in code...

Thank'

Class Code:

```
public class CityButton extends Button {
    private double ratioX;
    private double ratioY;
    private City city;

public CityButton(Context context, City city, double ratioX, double ratioY) {
    super(context);

    this.city = city;

    Rect boundRect = this.getBackground().getBounds();
    this.setHeight(boundRect.height());
    this.setWidth(boundRect.height());

    this.ratioX = ratioX;
    this.ratioY = ratioY;
}

public void addReinforcements(int value) {
    city.addReinforcements(value);
    reinforcementView.setText("" + city.getReinforcements());
}

public void setOffset(int posX, int posY) {
    int offsetX = (int) (posX * this.ratioX) - 5;
    int offsetY = (int) (posY * this.ratioY) - 5;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams());
    params.setMargins(offsetX, offsetY, offsetX + this.getWidth(), offsetY + this.getHeight());
    this.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `offsetX`, `offsetY`, `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` > 0?

Comment: No, didn't think it could be < 0, I'll try, but I parse an xml file for those, so I don't think they can

Comment: I checked and no, value are OK :/

Comment: pls post the code where you call `setBackgroundResource`

Comment: I call it many times in differents methods, I need to change the background resource many times. I always put a drawable resource (30*30px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `setBackgroundResource` may have the side effect of losing your offset settings. Try to call `setOffset` each time after you change background:

```
public void setBackgroundResource(int resid, int posX, int posY) {
    super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    setOffset(posX, posY);
}
```

Comment: Indeed doing that I can see the text, thank's, but now the button is completely deformed. I'll try to use setMaxWidth and setMaxHeight for that.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I could keep always the same height and width so the background won't be deformed? For the time being it depends how long the text is